# Saving and loading data to multiple UItextfields

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

I'm using this code to save data and load data within one UITextfeild. How can I save and load with multiply UITextfeilds?

```
- (IBAction) savedata:(id)sender
{
    NSString *savestring = firstname.text;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:savestring forKey:@"savestring"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (IBAction) loaddata:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:@"savestring"];
    [firstname setText:loadstring];
}
```

Comment: [core data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: @Kevin core-data is massive overkill to save a couple of strings.

Comment: Saved and loaded individually, or as a group? Just for display or needs to be searched / sent?

Comment: @rmaddy depends how many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access the text from each text field and save each value with a different key.

```
- (IBAction)savedata:(id)sender {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:firstname.text forKey:@"savedFirstName"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:lastname.text forKey:@"savedLastName"];
}
```

Repeat as needed for other text fields.

```
- (IBAction)loadData:(id)sender {
    firstname.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"savedFirstName"];
    lastname.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"savedLastName"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using this code to save data and load data within one UITextfeild.
>   How can I save and load with multiply UITextfeilds?

Wash, rinse, repeat:

```
- (IBAction) savedata:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *firstnameString = firstname.text;
    NSString *lastnameString = lastname.text;
    NSString *ageString = age.text;
    NSString *addressString = address.text;

    [defaults setObject:firstnameString forKey:@"firstname"];
    [defaults setObject:lastnameString forKey:@"lastname"];
    [defaults setObject:ageString forKey:@"age"];
    [defaults setObject:addressString forKey:@"address"];

    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Loading the data works the same way -- just repeat the same pattern you're already using with variables and keys appropriate for each piece of data.